# I'm learning about container gardening and I'm confused about the 30% potting, 70% repotting rule

Tags: containers, bonsai

In my class we learned to repot at 70% root coverage however as I am mostly interested in bonsai style planting I'm confused about this rule. If I am attempting to limit my plant to a certain height is there any reason I would need to repot and would I have to continuously have to get bigger pots for the same sized plant
?

Comment: I have a degree in Horticulture and I've never heard of this "rule". How are you supposed to determine when a plant is at 70% root coverage? By depotting it and taking a look? That's bad for most plants. It seems like there are a ton of gardening rules, but they're all really "guidelines" and some only apply to specific plants.

Comment: Root-bound plants flower for being slightly frightened by their limited territory. Good. Plants can be left in old pots until they scream for help. Bonsai small-pot-root-cramping is intrinsic to the dwarfing.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Jurp, I have never heard of this either.  Often people make up their own rules of thumbs and then they take off.

If you are interested in Bonsai-ing, then the last thing you want to do is to repot the plant.

Comment: IIRC (not really tilting at Bonsai personally) one might de-pot, root prune, and re-pot in the same pot some times. That's a bonsai only technique AFAIK